# What does it mean that an operations amplifier is 'high gain'?

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, operational-amplifier

I dont have much of a background in electronics, but need to know about operational amplifiers for my physics course. I keep reading the term 'high  gain'. What does this mean?

Comment: It means its (open loop) voltage amplification is high. High in this case could mean anything from 10,000 times upwards

Answer (score 2):

By **high** we mean a value that's adequate for a special purpose, typically in the range of 10,000 to 100,000. Op amps are most often used for feedback systems, therefore their open-loop gain, the gain obtained without any feedback connections, must be chosen in such a way that they meet the degree of precision that is needed for the closed-loop circuit.

Let me elaborate more on various parameters involving opamp circuitry. The following diagram shows a feedback amplifier. The block *G* is called the *basic amplifier*, and the block *H* is called the *feedback system*. 
[image]

What the feedback system does it sense the output voltage, Vo, and output a voltage fVo, where f is the less than one. This output feedback voltage, namely fVo, is then subtracted from the input voltage, Vi, and the difference is fed back to the basic amplifier. The ratio of the output voltage to the input voltage is called the *closed-loop gain*, which can be obtained by simply dividing Vo by Vi:

$$V_o=A(V_i-fV_0)$$ 
and therefore,

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{A}{1+Af}.$$
For this equation Af must be large compared to 1. It means that it depends on applications. Sometimes even a value of A=100 might give us the desired accuracy we want.

In the above equation as A approaches infinity the closed-loop gain tends to 1/f. This suggests that the closed-loop gain is now independent of open-loop gain variations, which is why opamps are widely used as active elements in circuits.

Comment: Note that there is a nasty trap in that statement, it only applies at low frequency (whatever that means for a particular opamp), open loop gain falls steadily above a very low corner frequency and hits unity at the frequency specified by the 'Gain-Bandwidth product', you need to make sure that the closed loop gain you are trying for is low enough for this limit not to matter given the frequency of your signals.

Comment: Thank you, the calculations are clear, but would you please also elaborate a bit more on why it is beneficial that in op-amps, the closed-loop gain is independent of the open-loop gain variations(assuming the gain is properly high)? You've said "this is why op-amps are widely used as active elements in circuits". But I don't understand why. (My guess is that this way, one will only be required to control the behavior of the circuit by adjusting the frequency and not being required to consider the internal of the op-amp used as well?)

Answer (score 0):

It means that the output voltage will be a huge number times the difference in voltage between the input terminals. Typically the "open-loop" gain will be > 1 million.

The funny effect of this is that it is almost useless as an amplifier in the open loop mode. We can, however, make very useful amplifiers by controlling the gain with negative feedback.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuz16H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A bare open-loop op-amp and an non-inverting amplifier with a gain of -10.*

A brief intuitive look at a non-inverting amplifier:

- Assume on power up that the output is zero volts and a 10 mV signal is applied to Vin.
- The + input is now +10 mV and the - input is at 0 V.
- If the op-amp has a gain of 1,000,000 then the output will start to rise and head towards 10 mV x 1,000,000 = 10,000 V. (In reality it can't go beyond the positive supply voltage.)
- As the output voltage rises the - input voltage rises at 1/10 the rate due to the 10:1 divider of R2 and R1. At output voltage of 100 mV there will be 10 mV on the - input and the positive-going "drive" on the output will reduce to zero. In fact the inverting input will settle at a value in the order of a microvolt below 10 mV.

The gain, A, of this circuit is now set by the feedback resistors to \$ A = \frac {R1+R2}{R1} \$.

Answer (score 0):

Without neglecting the (very high) open loop gain Ao of the opamp in the non-inverting configuration (see figure in transistor`s post) the closed-loop gain (with feedback applied) is

**Acl=Ao/[1+kAo]=1/[(1/Ao)+k]** with k=feedback factor=R1/(R1+R2)

As you can see, for (1/Ao<< k) identical to (Ao>>1/k) the closed-loop gain is practically determined by the feedback factor only and we arrive at

**Acl=1/k=1+R2/R1**.

For this reason, all opamps have very large open-loop gain Ao.